# What is the lowest transaction tax possible?

Tags: eve-online

What is the lowest possible transaction tax that you can get to in an npc station, and what do you need to do to get to that lowest point?

Are there skills or standings requirements that modify the transaction tax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lowest possible sales tax is 0.75% with Accounting 5. Standing does not affect it, and no other skills do either. Sales tax applies whenever you sell, whether it's an immediate sell or a longer-term sell order.

[Broker's fees](http://go-dl1.eve-files.com/media/corp/Thoraemond/eve-market-order-broker-fees-20110417.png) apply whenever you create a non-immediate sell or buy order. It is affected by both the Broker Relations skill, your standing from the corp owning the station, your standing from the faction of that corp. The lowest possible is 0.1875%.

Comment: Accounting decreases the tax by 10% per level, not only 5%.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Uniwiki on Trading](http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/Trading):

Trading Cost Modifiers

- Broker Relations (Rank 2) [Req: Trade 2] reduce base broker fee by 5%
  per level
- Accounting (Rank 3) [Req: Trade 4]: **reduces sales tax by
  10% per level**
- Margin Trading (Rank 3) [Req: Accounting 4]: reduces
  escrow requirement for buy orders by an additional 25% per level

Whenever you set up a buy or sell order, you will have to pay the broker fee: 1% of the total order (0.75% at max skills), modified by standings. **Whenever each unit gets sold, the seller will pay 1% of the sell price as a transaction tax (0.5% at max skills).** The fees show up in the wallet journal as "Brokers Fee" and "Transaction Tax".
So the typical station trader with zero standings will pay 2.454% of the order price as taxes, 2% at max skills. This is important to take into account when calculating your profit.

Comment: You're missing the effect of standings on the broker fees, which is rather significant.

Comment: @MadScientist - This question does not deal with broker fees, that is [What is the lowest broker fee possible?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/104499/what-is-the-lowest-broker-fee-possible/104504) My answer touches on the subject for faithfulness to the source.